# Is there a way to modify the dataframe passed to a facetgrid in seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot different layers in a facetgrid as follows:

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(data=tips, row='time', col='sex')
grid.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="smoker")
grid.map_dataframe(sns.scatterplot, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="smoker")
#.
#.
#.
# n number of plots
```

In the above example both the lineplot and scatterplot use the same dataframe tips. Now, I want to change the rows in the dataframe for different plots as follows:

```
tips = tips.head(n) # n is any number
```

So, for one plot I may have 120 rows of data whereas for another plot I will have 50 rows and so on.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can do is to wrap the plot functions around a UDF, then pass that function along with corresponding parameters to `map_dataframe`:

```
def my_plot_func(data, plot_func, num_rows, *args, **kwargs):
    plot_func(data=data.head(num_rows), *args, **kwargs)

grid = sns.FacetGrid(data=tips, row='time', col='sex')
grid.map_dataframe(my_plot_func, plot_func=sns.lineplot, num_rows=10, 
                   x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="smoker")
grid.map_dataframe(my_plot_func, plot_func=sns.scatterplot, num_rows=5,
                   x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="smoker")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Note that the "data" arg in the my_plot_func is special and refers to the dataframe as passed in the FacetGrid call.  That arg must literally be "data" and can't be replaced with an arg name, e.g. "df".